# Divorced Parents of Chosson/Kallah Escorting to Chupah

Tags: wedding, chupah

Many Poskim note the סימנא טובא of ensuring the couple escorting the chosson and kallah to the chupah are married to their first spouse [see [Teshuvos V’Hanhagos (2:652)](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20026&st=&pgnum=517&hilite=), [Minchas Yitzchak (5:80)](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1599&st=&pgnum=196&hilite=), and [Be’er Moshe (3:184)]](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=888&st=&pgnum=261&hilite=) , but in my limited experience it seems most newlyweds are escorted by parents even if they're divorced. What is the Torah-ideal method for the chupah when one's parents are separated?

[Not having anyone escort the chosson seems to counter the minhag mentioned in the [Rema YD (391:3)](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.391.3?vhe=Ashlei_Ravrevei:_Shulchan_Aruch_Yoreh_Deah,_Lemberg,_1888&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) to have two men escort the chosson]

Comment: Whatever makes for the most shalom bayis! (R' Yaakov Kaminetsky's practice on whether to have the parents walk the kallah vs. the mothers walk her? "Whatever the other side wants!")

Comment: @Shalom Theoretically, I agree completely. Unfortunately, divorces don't often lend themselves to peaceful resolutions at simchos - that's particularly why I'm wondering what halachic preferences the Poskim offer.